# Resize a Gallery in the parent page without Highlslide popping up

Tags: highslide

I really love the Highslide Gallery named "Gallery in the parent page without Highslide popping up at all", but I find it to be the most difficult one to customize among all HS galleries.

**I'm trying to resize its width**, but I am not able to do it.

I modified :
    // Options for the in-page items
    var inPageOptions = {
    width: 200,
    height: 300
    }

AND / OR

```
<div id="gallery-area" style="width: 220px; height: 320px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid silver">
```

**but nothing ever changed**  (I also tried to change the pictures width with Gimp)   :(

What should I modify?

Comment: For me changing width in `gallery-area` and in `inPageOptions` works perfectly fine (as long as images have proper size), see example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qfEx/

Comment: Thanks Powel, maybe I didn't resize the image properly or I messed everything up with CSS.
I erased my code and substituted it with yours...
NOW IT WORKS PERFECTLY

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of an in-page gallery (gallery in the parent page without Highslide popping up) without having to crop the images/change the size of the images.

- Change the `width` of the `gallery-area` div (you may also want to change
  the `height`)
- Change the `width` in `inPageOptions` (you may also want to change the
  `height`)
- And here's the important thing to do: Change `allowSizeReduction` in
  `inPageOptions` to `true` instead of `false`

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yf9X3/

```
<div id="gallery-area" style="width: 320px; height: 480px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid silver">
```

```
 // Options for the in-page items
 var inPageOptions = {
     //slideshowGroup: 'group1',
     outlineType: null,
     allowSizeReduction: true,
     wrapperClassName: 'in-page controls-in-heading',
     thumbnailId: 'gallery-area',
     useBox: true,
     width: 300,
     height: 400,
     targetX: 'gallery-area 10px',
     targetY: 'gallery-area 10px',
     captionEval: 'this.a.title',
     numberPosition: 'caption'
 };
```